# After List Migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013, One view has an error "List not found"

Tags: migration

List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Correlation ID:252bdc9e-efca-c033-393e-4837bb363a7c

Error after Migration. All the other views are available except one view. Not able to create new views as well. Look ups are all working fine.

Comment: Can you look in log sand provide detailed error related to correlation id ?

Comment: It seems some javascript code is added on page which is referencing the list guid hence list no found error.

Comment: This is a bit of a long-shot, but is there a look-up column in that view, perhaps the look-up is searching for something that has migrated?

Comment: I faced this issue a lot on custom pages during migration. My list ID was not getting updated with the new list ID on migration. Please update the list ID of list view web part with new list ID on which you are getting error and your view will start working.

Comment: It was the look ups.. when I created the lookup lists and then migrated the actual list.. it worked out.. had to do a lot of corrections.. still.. atleast the error was gone